# How to run CreateIndex function in Hyperspace (spark)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to create an index using hyperspace in pyspark.
But I am getting this error

```
sample_data = [(1, "name1"), (2, "name2")]
spark.createDataFrame(sample_data, ['id','name']).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("table")
df = spark.read.parquet("table")

from hyperspace import *
# Create an instance of Hyperspace
hyperspace = Hyperspace(spark)

hs.createIndex(df, IndexConfig("index", ["id"], ["name"]))
```

**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SerializableFileStatus cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus**

I am running on Azure databricks environment-
Spark 3.0.0 scala 2.12

When I try to do the same on spark 2.4.2 scala 2.12 or scala 2.11
I get the error in the same function (CreateIndex)
Here I get the following error-

**.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.com.microsoft.hyperspace.index.IndexConfig.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:**

Can anyone suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Per the last comment of https://github.com/microsoft/hyperspace/discussions/285, it is a known issue with Databricks runtime.

If you use open source spark, it should work.

Seeking a solution with Databricks team.